# Orthonormal basis matrix trace

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have $v_1,...,v_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^n$ and $A$ any $n \times n$ real or complex matrix, prove that:

$$Trace(A)=\sum_{i-1}^n Av_i\bullet v_i$$

I see that $v_i\bullet v_j=\delta_{ij}$ so it makes sense that it's true, but I can't quite see how to get there so any hints would be appreciated.

More generally we have that $A$ must be a linear combination of the basis elements:

$$Av_j=\sum_{i=1}^nb_{ij}v_i$$

We then have a matrix $B=b_{ij}$ so prove that:

$$Trace(A)=\sum_{i=1}^nb_{ii}$$

Comment: Isn't that the definition of trace? What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \cdots v_n \end{bmatrix}$, then $V^TV = I$.

By definition, $\operatorname{tr} A = \sum_k e_k^T A e_k$, and by the cyclic
property of trace we have 
$\operatorname{tr} A = \operatorname{tr} (A V V^T) = \operatorname{tr} (V^T A V) = \sum_k e_k^T V^T A V e_k = \sum_k v_k^T A v_k$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\sum_{i}v_i^HAv_i&=\sum_{i}\mathrm{trace}\{v_i^HAv_i\} \\&=\sum_{i}\mathrm{trace}\{Av_iv_i^H\} \\ &=\mathrm{trace}\{A\sum_{i}\left(v_iv_i^H\right)\} \\ &= \mathrm{trace}\{AVV^H\} && \mbox{V=[$v_1,\dots,v_n$]}\\ &= \mathrm{trace}\{A\}\end{align}